# RegEx to extract english text in between html content string using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I had a sample string like this.

```
<br> My first word, sentence 
<div class='test'><span class='abc'></span>
</div> <br>between 1185–1667 <div> my second sentence, 1223 <span>some nested text 123</span></div>
<span> my third word, asdf 1234 and fourth word</span>
```

I need a regular expression to extract English text in JavaScript, the result to be like this

```
var result=[
"My first word, sentence",
"between",
"my second sentence",
"some nested text",
"my third word, asdf",
"and fourth word"
]
```

Comment: And what if you find nested element?

Comment: Hi just extract English text in sequence,  the nested element sequence no need to follow , the final string is from left to right-- updated in question

Comment: @Kiran I'm pretty sure JavaScript regular expressions are not sufficiently powerful for that task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```js
str = "<br> My first word, sentence <div class='test'><span class='abc'></span></div> <br>between 1185–1667 <div> my second sentence, 1223 <span>some nested text 123</span></div><span> my third word, asdf 1234 and fourth word</span>";

function getEnglishText(text){
    var arr = text.replace(/\s?[0-9][^A-z<>]+/g, '<a>').split(/\s?<[^<>]+>\s?/g);
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        arr[i] = arr[i].replace(/,$/,'');
        if(/(^\s+$|^$)/.test(arr[i])){
            arr.splice(i,1);
            i--;
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

console.log(getEnglishText(str));
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I don't think that regex is appropriet for this situation nor you find this spliting usfull but here is what i made

```js
const data = `<br> My first word, sentence 
<div class='test'><span class='abc'></span>
</div> <br>between 1185–1667 <div> my second sentence, 1223 </div>
<span> my third word, asdf 1234 and fourth word</span>`

function split(html) {
    const regex = /<.*?>([^]*?)(?=<.*?>)/g
    let tmp, out = []
    while (tmp=regex.exec(html)) {
        tmp[1] = tmp[1].trim()
        if (tmp[1]) out.push(tmp[1])
    }
    return out
}
const out = split(data)

console.log(out)
```

Comment: Great thank you for quick help. is it possible to do some change to remove numbers?  actually, the last string has to be split into two.